# Facing issue when adding python JWT library in Google App Engine Project

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to integrate Python JWT package https://github.com/davedoesdev/python-jwt into my GAE project

After adding this into lib folder I am getting below error

"Unresolved import Error"

after running the project it shows "no module named JWT"

Please help me on this.

Comment: is `JWT` in uppercase in the message? Imports are case-sensitive and `jwt` is imported using lowercase.

Comment: No We are using smaller case only.

Comment: Are you getting this error on the local development server? How are you setting up the import from lib/ ?